# How to iterate over columns of "spark" dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I have the following Spark dataframe that is created dynamically

| name|  number |

+--------+---------+

| Andy | (20,10,30)|

|Berta | (30,40,20)|

| Joe  | (40,90,60)|

+-------+---------+

Now, I need to iterate each row and column in Spark to print the following output, How to do this?

Andy    20

Andy    10

Andy    30

Berta   30

Berta   40

Berta   20

Joe     40

Joe     90

Joe     60

Comment: Hi, pls reveal sructure of the DF. explode should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the number column is of string Data Type, you can achieve the desired results by following below steps.

Original Data Frame:

```
         val df = Seq(("Andy", "20,10,30"), ("Berta", "30,40,20"), ("Joe", "40,90,60"))
         .toDF("name", "number")
```

Then Create an intermediate Data Frame having 3 number columns by splitting the number column with comma.

```
  val Interim_Df = df.withColumn("n1", split(col("number"), ",").getItem(0))
  .withColumn("n2", split(col("number"), ",").getItem(1))
  .withColumn("n3", split(col("number"), ",").getItem(2))
  .drop("number")
```

Then generate the final result data frame by doing union with oneIndexDfs.

```
val columnIndexes = Seq(1, 2, 3)

val onlyOneIndexDfs = columnIndexes.map(x =>
  Interim_Df.select(
    $"name",
    col(s"n$x").alias("number")))

val resultDF = onlyOneIndexDfs.reduce(_ union _)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need **explode** function.
[Here samples of its usage.](https://hadoopist.wordpress.com/2016/05/16/how-to-handle-nested-dataarray-of-structures-or-multiple-explodes-in-sparkscala-and-pyspark/)